# Problems with insydeh20 setup utility rev 5.0 after installing fedora os 38

Tags: fedora, boot, windows

I have installed fedora OS 38, before that I had windows 11, now I want to install windows again through bios, but my boot options became strange, I decided to look up boot options and came across this:
[image]

And if I try to boot with BIOS using F2 button with flash drive plugged in, it just hangs with the ACER start screen.
What should I do to fix it?